# SQL - How to join product table to the customer table?

Tags: sql

I have a customer table

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 001 |
| Bill | 002 |

and a purchased product table

| CustomerID | ProductID | Quantity | TotalQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Pen | 3 | 4 |
| 001 | Mug | 1 | 4 |
| 002 | Pen | 5 | 7 |
| 002 | Hat | 1 | 7 |
| 002 | Cap | 1 | 7 |

Is there a way to join the total quantity to the customer table and count the rows of results like this?

| Name | ID | Total | Returned_Rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 001 | 4 | 2 |
| Bill | 002 | 7 | 2 |

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Why do you have a TotalQuantity column? You shouldn't store values calculated from other data.

Answer (score 0):

It' simple to join tables and group them by customer id

```
select c.Name, c.ID, SUM(Quantity) Total , COUNT(*) Retuurned_Rows
from product p
inner join customer c
  on p.customerId = c.Id
group by c.ID , c.Name
```